# Package C++ extension using setuptools along with a stub file

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

So I have the following file structure:

```
project/
├─ cpp_src/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ cpp source files
│  ├─ test/
│  │  ├─ cpp test files
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ stub.pyi
├─ python_src/
│  ├─ ...
├─ build.py
```

In my `build.py` file, I am using setuptools to compile and package the C++ extension in `cpp_src` using a custom `build_ext` command. However, I can't seem to get this to include the stub file `stub.pyi`. How can I modify the setuptools command to do this? I'm not that concerned about the file structure, so if another `setup.py` file is needed in `cpp_src`, thats fine.

I'm also using Poetry to manage the virtual environment if that helps. Moreover, if there is another build system which will make this easier, I'd be happy to use that.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is a reduced version of the `build.py` file (full repo here https://github.com/Aspect1103/Hades/tree/generation-rust):

```py
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def build_extension(self, ext: Extension) -> None:
        # Determine where the extension should be transferred to after it has been
        # compiled
        current_dir = Path.cwd()
        build_dir = current_dir.joinpath(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)).parent

        # Determine the profile to build the CMake extension with
        profile = "Release"

        # Make sure the build directory exists
        build_temp = Path(self.build_temp).joinpath(ext.name)
        if not build_temp.exists():
            build_temp.mkdir(parents=True)

        # Compile and build the CMake extension
        subprocess.run(
            [
                "cmake",
                current_dir.joinpath(ext.sources[0]),
                f"-DDO_TESTS=false",
                f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_{profile.upper()}={build_dir}",
            ],
            cwd=build_temp,
            check=True,
        )
        subprocess.run(
            ["cmake", "--build", ".", f"--config {profile}"], cwd=build_temp, check=True
        )


def main():
    setup(
        name="hades_extensions",
        script_args=["bdist_wheel"],
        ext_modules=[Extension("hades_extensions", ["cpp_src"])],
        cmdclass={"build_ext": CMakeBuild},
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.py` file?  Maybe a full repository link on Github?

Comment: @blong I've updated the post with my build script

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is presently a way to install a `.pyi` file directly alongside the `.so` in the file structure, but you can exploit [PEP 561's stub-only packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages) to create a separate package inside the repo containing just your stub, which will then be installed and recognised by compliant IDEs.

- Create a new directory inside your repo that must specifically called `my_pkg-stubs` (as per [PEP 561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages))
- Rename `my_pkg.pyi` to `my_pkg-stubs/__init__.pyi`
- In your `setup.py`, add the `my_pkg-stubs` package, and ensure the `.pyi` file will be included in the distro:

```
...
    packages=[..., 'my_pkg-stubs'],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={"my_pkg-stubs": ["*.pyi"]},
...
```

When `my_pkg` and `my_pkg-stubs` are both installed, a PEP561-compliant IDE will look in `my_pkg-stubs` for type hints, and automatically display them. I've verified this behaviour using Visual Studio Code on a [repo](https://github.com/ideoforms/signalflow/) that I've applied this process to.